# How to output data when using $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do you correctly output data when using `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`? Right now I'm getting single words as my result when doing

```
"select name, author, title from d_books"

// Other PDO stuff goes here
$arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($arr as $titleData) {
   echo $titleData['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 $pdo = new PDO(/*Your credentials*/);
 $sql = `select name, author, title from d_books`
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute(); 

 while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $arr['name'];
 }
```

or

```
 $pdo = new PDO(/*Your credentials*/);
 $sql = `select name, author, title from d_books`
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute(); 
 $arr = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach ($arr as $titleData) {
    echo $titleData['name'];
 }
```

You can always use `pdo->query()` method when running a query without any parameters, which is faster, but I do not believe that this happens much(running queries without any parameters).

Comment: Your answers work. I was using `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`. Maybe that's why I kept getting single letters as my output.