# Returning an array with PDO - using FetchAll doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, pdo, fetch, fetchall

I use the following code to retrieve data from my database. The problem is that it only displays the first row. In this particular case, it means that only the first picture is shown on the webpage but I want to show all of them.

```
<?php 
    $sql = "SELECT `image-id`, `article-id`, `image-path`, `image-title` FROM `table-images` WHERE `article-id` = :id";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
?>

<a class="swipebox" href="<?php echo $result['image-path'];?>" title="<?php echo $result['image-title'];?>">
<img alt="image" src="<?php echo $result['image-path'];?>"></a>

<?php
    }// end if
    else {
    echo '0 results';
    }// end else
?>
```

I read **[this article](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)** so I tried to use the code:

`if($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));?`

... but that doesn't work. It doesn't even echo the first picture anymore. What am I missing here?

Comment: Use a `while` loop. Edit: I was just about to mention a `foreach` loop, just as the answer appeared below.

Comment: `while ($arr = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { echo $arr['name']; }` as taken from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19364078/ you have two ways to do this. A `while` or a `foreach`, you can take your pick.

Comment: To explain what your present code is doing is this: Your conditional statement is checking **if** a result exists; and if so, it will echo only a single result because you are not looping till it doesn't find any others in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked with the `while` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how it works:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
$success = $stmt->execute();

if($success){
    //fetch here
}
```

Now you have 2 options for fetching the data:

**fetch()**

`fetch()` will get rows one by one so you need a while loop.

```
while($rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 // get data
}
```

**fetchAll()**

`fetchAll()` get all the rows at once so no need for loops to retrieve the data, but if you need to loop then you will need a for loop.

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly the information I was looking for.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with fetch() vs fetchAll() not returning all the rows in the db. I found that if you use fetcha() with a while loop it returns missing the first row. While using fetchAll with foreach returns all the rows. Maybe there's something I'm missing. An explanation would be great! Thank you

Comment: @ChrisKsag `fetch()` fetches the record one by one, until the cursor reaches the end of the recordset. To me it sounds like you called `fetch()` once before the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
    $sql = "Your SQL query";
    $id  = 1; 

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

    if($stmt->rowCount()){

       foreach($result as $row){
         echo $row['row_name'].'<br/>'; 
       }

    }else{
       echo 'No results found'; 
    }
```

Comment: for your answer to work properly you need to use `fetchAll` , I fixed it for you